# How to modify/check google cloud run's retry limit on failure?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I have got a topic, which on publish it pushes the event to a cloud run endpoint and I got a trigger on a storage bucket to publish for this topic. The container in the cloud run fails to process the event and it has been restarted over hundreds of times and I don't wanna waste money on this. How can I limit the retry on failure on a cloud run's container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible answer to the puzzle might be the following notion.

If we read the documentation on PUSH subscriptions found [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#receiving_push_messages), we find the following:

> ... Pub/Sub retries delivery until the message expires after the
>   subscription's message retention period.

What this means is that if Pub/Sub pushes a message to Cloud Run and Cloud Run does not acknowledge the message by returning a 200 response code, then the message will be re-pushed for the "message retention period".  By default, this is 7 days but according to the documentation, can be set to a minimum value of 10 minutes.  What this seems to say to me is that we can stop a poison message after 10 minutes (minimum) of retries.

If a message is pushed and not acked, then it won't be pushed again immediately but instead be pushed as a function of a back-off algorithm described [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#quotas_limits_and_delivery_rate).

Comment: That must be it! Thank you!

Comment: Further thinking ... it seems to me that the consumer of the message (Cloud Run in our case) could return a 200 response code which would consume the message.  If we define "Returning 200 means don't send me the message again".  This would then push the onus on what whether we want to process the message again to the consumer.

Comment: Yes, but my problem was that about an error occurs during processing the message. Can't return the response before processing can we? Anyways the reducing message retention period worked!

Comment: Howdy Mark, glad that the suggestion worked.  As for an error occurring during the message processing ... most languages have exception handlers / try/catch handlers that could potentially be used to trap an error and perform some remedial or cleanup work.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the [gcloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/subscriptions/create#--max-delivery-attempts) we find reference to the concept of a maximum number of delivery attempts (`--max-delivery-attempts`).  Associated with this is a topic called the dead letter topic (`--dead-letter-topic`).  What this appears to define is that if an attempt to deliver a pub sub message more than the maximum number of times, the message will be removed from the queue of messages associated with the subscription and moved to the topic associated with the dead letter.  If you define this for your environment, then your Cloud Run will only execute a finite number of times after which the *poision* messages will be moved elsewhere.

Comment: in the reference for the `--max-delivery-attempts` it says defaults to 5. Why did not this happen?

Comment: Well ... huh!!!   It seems that this function is part of an "alpha" release of function for Pub/Sub and not generally available to all as of this date.  I'm thinking its a mistake that it appears in the ordinary gcloud doc area.

Comment: What do you mean by `this function`? Pub/Sub should not have this kind of big flaw, I don't think I messed up the topic+subscription combo.

Comment: Sorry ... I wasn't clear.  GCP Pub/Sub does NOT have Dead Letter queue processing currently available as part of its spec.  This means that the --max-delivery-attempts and --dead-letter-topic are not yet available for use.  The documentation on the web that describes these parameters appears to be "alpha" documentation.  If you wish, just post here and I'll delete this answer entirely.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I could use the max-delivery-attempts but still does not work. Anyways how is that possible that normal pub/sub configuration does this infinite loop on error?